# Jackson annotation @get:JsonValue, GSON equivalent

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, gson

Is there a GSON equivalent annotation for Jackson's  `@get:JsonValue`?

I have the below enum and I need the GSON annotation as well.

```
enum class TransactionType(@get:JsonValue val code: Int) { ... }
```

Comment: I'm familiar with Jackson's `@JsonValue` and not `@get:JsonValue` (so a link to that would be appreciated) so this may not be helpful but are you looking for `@SerializedName`?  https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html

Comment: The answer is probably there but I cant say its easily extractable

Comment: `@get:` just means that the annotation will be attached to the getter, not the field. Nothing stops you from doing that in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was:

```
enum class Type(@get:JsonValue val code: Int, val description: String) {
    @SerializedName("0") NEGATIVE(2, "negative amount "),
    @SerializedName("1") CREDIT(3,"Credit."),
    @SerializedName("2") WAGERS(6,"wager"),
    @SerializedName("3") ZERO(8, "zero.")
}
```

Reference:
https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1/com/google/gson/annotations/package-summary.html